# UIActivityViewController presenting issue iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[message] applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = nil;
[activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
 {
     activityVC.completionHandler = nil;
//         if (completed)
//             [Utils alertMessage:kNSLocalizedString(@"TITLE20_KEY#0", nil) title:nil delegate:nil cancelButton:kNSLocalizedString(@"OK_KEY#0", nil) otherButton:nil hiden:nil];
         [activityVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
             _isSharing = NO;
         }];
     }];

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)]) {
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
}

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{
    _isSharing = YES;
}];
```

I am getting the below warning.

> Warning: Attempt to present 
>   on  which is already presenting (null)

Comment: Actually the problem was UIActivityViewController load twice. We are using the LongPress Gesture for loading the UIActivityViewController And it call twice. Now I have handle this. Thanks for the suppport

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to call the function contains presenting `UIActivityViewController`

```
[self performSelector: @selector(urMethodToPresentActivityController) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0.1];`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for your Viewcontroller as its giving self as null.

You can check tutorial for UIActivityViewController from below link

http://www.amaniphoneblog.com/2014/09/uiactivityviewcontroller-ios-tutorial.html